# What is the MIME validation for excel files on Vue Formulate.?

Tags: vue.js, vue-formulate

What is the MIME type for excel files on Vue Formulate

I've tried

```
<FormulateInput
      type="image"
      name="headshot"
      label="Select an image to upload"
      :uploader="uploadFile"
      help="Select a png, jpg or gif to upload."
      validation="mime:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    />
```

but this doesn't seem to work. how do I validate if the selected file is indeed a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default mime list that vue formulate ships with is [very small](https://github.com/wearebraid/vue-formulate/blob/master/src/libs/mimes.js). However extending the list is pretty easy:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate'

Vue.use(VueFormulate, {
  mimes: {
    xls: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    // ... any other mimes
  }
})
```

There's documentation around this here: https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/types/file/#mime-types

*Full Disclosure: I'm Vue Formulate’s author.*